# Android setcookie and setAcceptCookie method crash in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to set cookie in my app, so I used API method `setAcceptCookie` and `setCookie` in my code. This runs well when SDK version > 19, but in SDK version 18, my app crashed.

Below is my code. If I remove that to call method, it runs fine, so how can I do this?

```
try {
        final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        for (final String cookie : cookies) {
            Log.d(">>>>>>> inject Cookie into : " + url  + "  ==> " + cookie);
            cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookie);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Logcat output:

```
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm: "AsyncBackgroundTask #1" prio=5 tid=16 RUNNABLE
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41e2d8d0 self=0x5fb82498
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=25336 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1578780720
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 289179937 1233023039 1600 ) utm=23 stm=5 core=3
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at android.webkit.CookieManagerClassic.nativeSetAcceptCookie(Native Method)
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at android.webkit.CookieManagerClassic.setAcceptCookie(CookieManagerClassic.java:44)
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at coj.execute(RealCall.java:69)
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at XXXX
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at xxxxx
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-10 16:51:35.351 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-10 16:51:35.361 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-10 16:51:35.361 25280-25336/? I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure use CookieSyncManager

```
    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
    cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookie);
    cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
    cookieSyncMngr.sync();
```